# NiFi 1.9.1 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jbdc.driver.OrcaleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, apache-nifi

I try connect NiFi to Oracle over JBDC and have this error:

```
2020-08-13 12:48:48,568 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2020-08-13 12:48:48,568 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
2020-08-13 12:48:59,438 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode DBCPConnectionPool[id=e252cec4-0173-1000-c06c-964690e5251c] Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method due to org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver: {}
org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getDriverClassLoader(DBCPConnectionPool.java:427)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.onConfigured(DBCPConnectionPool.java:366)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor638.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceNode$2.run(StandardControllerServiceNode.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jbdc.driver.OrcaleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getDriverClassLoader(DBCPConnectionPool.java:416)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
2020-08-13 12:48:59,438 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of DBCPConnectionPool[id=e252cec4-0173-1000-c06c-964690e5251c] due to org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver
```

I put `ojdbc7.jar` in /lib/nifi-serve/lib and restart nifi service after that.
Why NiFi can't load driver?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a typo: It's not `oracle.jdbc.driver.OrcaleDriver`, it's `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`